Comparing decimals within a LINQ query using a SQLite-database fails with operators but works with .CompareTo
In my SQLite database, I have a table foo that contains a column bar that is of data type decimal. I want to retreive all rows, where the value of bar is > 100.
If I try to execute the query like this:
var result = from r in db.Foo
             where r.Bar > 100
             select Bar;

I get the following error:
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Foo>.Where(r => r.Bar > 100)' could not be translated. 

Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, 
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either 
AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

However, if I rewrite the query to use .CompareTo() instead of >, it works without a problem:
var result = from r in db.Foo
             where r.Bar.CompareTo(100) > 0
             select r;

I don't quite get why the first query works but the second one does not since they basically do the same things. Does .CompareTo() trigger client-side evaluation?

try where r.Bar > 100m => floating point literals - not sure if that's enough, though. Just a suspicion.

Side-note: i dont think this is a sqlite related problem, seems more like a LINQ related one. Maybe change the title? :)

Could still depend on the database driver in use, though. Translation may work (allthough I am doubtful) if you were to connect to, say MS SQL Server or MySQL.

@Fildor  I tried using 100m, unfortunately I got the same error. You are right, when I use MS-SQL the translation works

And in Fluent-API it fails, too? db.Foo.Where(r => r.Bar > 100.0m).Select(r => r.Bar).ToList(); ?

Yes, using Fluent-API fails too with the same error message.

decimal isn't supported and doesn't even exist in SQLite. SQLite has no data types, only storage classes. Numbers can be stored as INTEGER or REAL or even TEXT. The EF Core SQLite provider explicitly says that decimal isn't supported and provides alternatives

The SQLite Data Types docs explain the various storage classes and how numeric(..) types can be stored in various formats

@PanagiotisKanavos It also states: EF Core can read and write values of these types, and querying for equality (where e.Property == value) is also supported. Other operations, however, like comparison and ordering will require evaluation on the client. In my example, the comparison with > does not work, but .CompareTo works and I am wondering why.

CompareTo doesn't do what you assume. It does not compare values, it calculates a result that needs to get compared with something else. As a result, it can't take advantage of any indexes and will be slower. Use ToQueryString to see what the actual SQL query is.

I totally forgot about that. I knew it was something to do with SQLite itself ...

Which EF Core and provider version are you using? The numeric function mappings docs show that such comparisons are translated to ef_compare(@decimalValue, @d) < 0. The function ef_compare is a custom extension added by the provider itself.

I am using EF Core 3.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1

I managed to get the generated SQL-query by entity framework: SELECT "p"."Bar" FROM "Foo" AS "p" WHERE CASE WHEN "p"."Bar" = '100.0' THEN 0 WHEN "p"."Bar" > '100.0' THEN 1 WHEN "p"."Bar" < '100.0' THEN -1 END > 0. It seems like entity framework converts the 100 to a TEXT and executes the comparison that way.

.NET Core 3 (and EF Core 3) went out of support 2 years ago. The oldest supported LTS version is .NET 8. There's no good reason to use such an old version in new projects. You wouldn't have any problems if you used the supported versions

I totally agree with you, if this was for a new project, I would use the latest LTS-versions. Unfortunately, as is so often the case, I have to support and further develop existing software and can't simply use the latest libraries.

You can't keep using end-of-life libraries either. With such old software (2 long-term versions behind), the company and the users are at risk from any unpatched security issues. And as the libraries are EOL, the vendor (ie you or your company) have to support them. Migrating from .NET 3 to 6 and then to 8 (or even directly) isn't as tricky as you assume.

This is an internal tool so no customer would be harmed and you don't have to tell me, that it's not a good idea to use EOL libraries. We plan to update everything to LTS but it is not as simple, because we are also using .net 4.7.2, WCF and other legacy stuff. If you have ever worked with legacy software, you should be familiar with the troubles that come with such upgrades.

SQLite doesn't natively support decimal, however, EF Core can read and write values of these types, and querying for equality. [Source] This is why Bar > 100 does not work and is throwing an error.
The reason why Bar.CompareTo(100) > 0 works, is, because entity framework translates .CompareTo into the following query:
SELECT 
    "p"."Bar"
FROM 
    "Foo" AS "p"
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN "p"."Bar" = '100.0' THEN 0
        WHEN "p"."Bar" > '100.0' THEN 1
        WHEN "p"."Bar" < '100.0' THEN -1
    END > 0

Here, entity framework converts the 100 to a TEXT and does the comparison that way.
This is probably not a very efficient way of handling the comparison. A better way would be to convert Bar to a double like so:
var result = from r in db.Foo
             where (double)r.Bar > 100
             select Bar;

The resulting SQL-query is:
SELECT 
    "p"."Bar" 
FROM 
    "Foo" AS "p" 
WHERE 
    CAST("p"."Bar" AS REAL) > 100.0

